# Get specific value in python nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

So when I print dictionary it gives:

```
u'Tags': [{u'Value': 'stone', u'Key': 'primary-key'}, {u'Value': 'hello world', u'Key': 'Name'}, {u'Value': '123 Street', u'Key': 'Address'}]
```

I need value of Key 'Name' i-e "Hello world"

I tried this:

```
for t in Tags:
    print(t["Name"])
```

but get error:

```
KeyError: 'Name'
```

Comment: `Name` is value! you must use key

Comment: u'Value': 'hello world' --> t['Value'] will give you. It is wronf to use Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'Name'` here is not a key, it is a value.  Your dictionaries all have keys of `u'Key'` and `u'Value'` which might be slightly confusing.

This should work for your example though:

```
for t in Tags:
    if t['Key'] == 'Name':
        print t['Value']
```

Answer (score 2):

In the dictionary, the entry `Tags` points to a list of objects with key and value as nested entries. Therefore, the access is not direct and requires a search of the key. It can be done using a simple list comprehension:

```
d = {u'Tags': [{u'Value': 'stone', u'Key': 'primary-key'},
               {u'Value': 'hello world', u'Key': 'Name'},
               {u'Value': '123 Street', u'Key': 'Address'}]}

name = next((v for v in d['Tags'] if v['Key'] == 'Name'), {}).get('Value')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find a "key name":

```
findYourWord ='hello world'

for dictB in dictA[u'Tags']:
    for key in dictB:
        if dictB[key]== findYourWord:
            print(key)
```

Hope this help you. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

In your inner dictionaries, the only keys are 'Key' and 'Value'. Try to make a function to find the value of the key you want, try:

```
def find_value(list_to_search, tag_to_find):
    for inner_dict in list_to_search:
        if inner_dict['Key'] == tag_to_find:
            return inner_dict['Value']
```

Now:

```
In [1]: my_dict = {u'Tags': [{u'Value': 'stone', u'Key': 'primary-key'}, {u'Value': 'hello world', u'Key': 'Name'}, {u'Value': '123 Street', u'Key': 'Address'}]}


In [2]: find_value(my_dict['Tags'], 'Name')
Out[2]: 'hello world'
```